# How to determine selection of row by month in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Problem: I want to select row in MySql based on user supplied month value, checking should go through all the records and check each date coloum by month. 
I have a table lets say

```
id int(4), date date
```

Now I want to retrieve this data using select statement, in the select statement i want to check the date by month not by the whole date because user has suppllied value in month ! whole date.

For example I want to make this kind of query:

```
select * 
  from `Table` 
 where id=123 
   And date = "value in month"
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) part.

```
SELECT ...
WHERE MONTH(date) = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE id = 123 
   AND MONTH(date) = 3
```

If your care for year also then

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1 
 WHERE id = 123 
   AND MONTH(date) = 3 -- March
   AND YEAR(date)  = 2013
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9243/1)** (for both queries)

*Note that no indexes will be used on `date` column even if they exist.*

Comment: thank you ... can i update this query as :
month = 3

SELECT * 
  FROM Table 
  WHERE id=123 
   AND MONTH(date) = "&Month&"
   AND YEAR(date)  = 2013

Comment: How about updating your question to state what you actually want?

Comment: @snowman You mean in ASP? If yes then go ahead. But keep in mind that this approach is prone to sql injections. So you better use parameterized queries.